# Add values inside foreach powershell

Tags: powershell, aws-cli, powershell-4.0

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($region in (Get-AWSRegion)) {
    $images = aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[ImageId]' | sort | uniq -c
}

$images
```

Above code gives me something like:

```
3 ami-123**
```

But I am trying to get all AMI's inside all regions together so it should be something like:

```
9 ami-123**
```

When I try something like:

```
$images += aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[ImageId]' | sort | uniq -c
```

I get: 
3 ami-123** 3 ami-123** 3 ami-123**

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: While you iterate Regions your aws command doesn't take the currently iterated Region into account, so why do you do this 1st place?

Comment: LotPings - So how can I change this? I am basically trying to get all unique ami's in all regions and run an operation on that. My thought was if I get all unique ami's from all regions then it is less overhead to run a query on each ami.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three immediate problems - first, you keep overwriting the value of `$images` inside the loop, and as you've found you can solve that by *adding* to the previous result set.

Second problem is that you're not actually targeting the `$region`, so you keep getting the same result from the default region configured for `aws` - specify `--region $region` inside the loop (assuming that `Get-AWSRegion` returns the region identifier as a string).

Third problem is a bit more... fundamental - the `aws` cli returns a string, so you'll need to manually parse that and aggregate the results - you could do so with a `[hashtable]` and a simple regex pattern:

```bsh
# Create hashtable to aggregate results
$ImageIDCounts = @{}

foreach($region in Get-AWSRegion){
    $perRegionCount = aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[ImageId]' | sort | uniq -c
    foreach($entry in $perRegionCount){
        if($entry -match '^\s*(\d+)\s+(.*)$'){
            $Count = $Matches[1] -as [int]
            $ImageID = $Matches[2].Trim()

            $ImageIDCounts[$ImageID] += $Count 
        }
    }
}
```

`$ImageIDCounts` now contains one entry per unique ImageID, so you can do:

```
$ami123count = $ImageIDCounts['ami-123']
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I was not looking for count though only unique image id's. I will try to get that from above solution.

Comment: I've no clue, but I guess there are other options for `--output`, not just text ;-) Reading the docs could help [AWS Command Line Interface - User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/aws-cli.pdf)

Comment: @NoviceMe That's as easy as just grabbing the hashtable keys: `$UniqueImageIDs = $ImageIDCounts.Keys`

Comment: @LotPings indeed, although you'll still need to do _some level of post-processing_ on the output (`ConvertFrom-JSON`, `XmlDocument.Load()` etc.) - `aws` is an external executable so the output is _always_ strings :)